# ANOSIM (vegan): Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 'x' must be atomic

Tags: r, vegan

I am using the **vegan** package for R and I am trying to do an **ANOSIM** but keeps getting this error message when doing the **summary()**:

```
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

Everything else works, it is just the summary that results in this error.
This is my code:

```
abund <- read.csv("fish.csv", sep=";", header=T)
site <- read.delim("station.txt", sep="\t", header=T)

distancematrix <- vegdist(abund, method="bray")
ANOSIMsite <- anosim(distancematrix, site$station)
summary(ANOSIMsite)
```

I have really tried everything and read all answers I could find on similar problems but without any luck...

I think the problem lies in the "*distancematrix*" but I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If this is a duplicate of a previous message, then the problem was fixed in vegan 2.3-0 of May 26, 2015 (current version is 2.4-1). If you're using older vegan, please upgrade. If the problem still persists, report the problem again. The function would still fail, but error message is informative and tells the clear reason.